# Extract indices of a NumPy array

Tags: performance, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, scikit-image

I have a NumPy array consisting of only the 0 and 1 elements as follows:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 1 , 1 , **1** , 1 , 1 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0]])
```

I have to find out the indices of the element 1 which is surrounded by 1 in 2 by 2 pixels in every directions.

The location of the expected answer is shown in bold.

I am looking for easier and faster way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy with a [basic morphological operation](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/erode.htm):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_erosion


data = np.array([[1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0]])

expected = np.array([[0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                     [0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                     [0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                     [0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                     [0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                     [0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                     [0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0]])

# otherwise known as np.ones((5, 5))
structuring_element = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

# will be of dtype np.bool but you can convert with .astype(np.int)
# if you really need
result = binary_erosion(data, structuring_element)

print(result)

print(np.allclose(result, expected))
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use some [`signal processing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) -

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

# Input
data = np.array([[1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0]])

# Extent of the search           
extent = 2;

# Kernel to be used with 2D convolution                 
kernel = np.ones((2*extent+1,2*extent+1))

# Perform 2D convolution with input data and kernel 
filt_out = signal.convolve2d(data, kernel, boundary='symm', mode='same')

# Find where the convolution resulted in a perfect score, 
# i.e is equal to the number of elements in kernel
R,C = np.where( filt_out == kernel.size )
```

Output -

```
In [66]: print(R,C)
[3] [4]
```

---

Listed in this section is an alternative approach with [`ndimage`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/ndimage.html) to perform the same convolution as with the previous approach, keeping rest of the steps same. Here's the code to get the convolution output `filt_out` -

```
import scipy.ndimage
filt_out = scipy.ndimage.convolve(data,kernel)
```

Comment: Thanks for your attempt. I have upvoted. However, I was thinking of doing it using scipy.ndimage. Can you propose me an alternative method?

Comment: like maximum_filter, minimum_filter?

Comment: @EricBal I don't think max or min filter would work here, but those filter would look for maximum value within that window. What we want is that all elements within that window to be `ones`. So what we need is summing of all elements within that window, so convolution would suit here.

Comment: @EricBal Added alternative approach with `ndimage`, which might be easier to follow?

Comment: So, what's the meaning of filt_out == np.sum(kernel.ravel())?

Comment: @EricBal That `ravel` reshapes the array into a 1D array, which makes it easier to get the sum of the elements in that array. The basic intention there was to get the number of elements in `kernel`. As an after-thought, you can use `kernel.size` instead to get the number of elements in it. Edited with it.

Comment: So, what's the meaning of R,C = np.where( filt_out == kernel.size )? Sorry for asking alot...

Comment: I mean what the convolution calculated 25 as the central pixel value?

Comment: @EricBal Yes, the convolution output updates the center pixel only. So, `filt_out` would have the convoluted output and in it the perfect score is reached when there is a `5x5` window in `data` that has all ones. This only happens at `(3,4)` in data where the convoluted output would be `25` because all 25 elements within that window in `data` were ones. So, we need to compare the convoluted output `filt_out` with the value `25` and see where there is a match and that is done with `==` to give us a logical array. Then, we use `np.where` to find indices of all TRUE values in that logical array.

Comment: @EricBal As docs say, it's the way the boundaries are to be treated for convolution. So, with `symm`, I think it basically replicates elements beyond the boundaries as mirror reflections. Look at this MATLAB function that uses the same terminology - http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html. That `symm` basically means `symmetric`.