# Extract Indices at Steps

Tags: numpy

I have a numpy array as shown in figure consisting of red and yellow pixels. I wan to select only the red ones.
[image]

```
import numpy as np
data = np.ones((10, 10))
```

How it is done, guys?

Comment: This is not a very user-friendly question at the moment. Can you please add runnable code? Right now someone has to go and add dozens of commas just to paste your data into their environment. Try the output of `print(data.__repr__())` if `data` is actually a NumPy array. And just as important, please add example output so that your what you want ("True values at every 2 steps over the rows and columns"?) is not ambiguous. Your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29512485/553404) with (more or less) runnable code, imports and indication of the answer you wanted is a lot clearer.

Comment: Help us help you. This is still a bad question...how is `answer` derived from `data`? Remember we have never seen this issue before and we can't read your mind. Explain the steps in words too and we can show you how to write the corresponding syntax.

Comment: Afraid not. I am not sure what you mean by "extract" in this case. And I definitely don't know what you mean by "extract every single True values from the kernel of np.ones(3,3) over the true values.". Maybe someone else will. Suggest you write down the expected result by hand, add it to your question, then explain in a few sentences how you did it by hand - imagine you were instructing someone else to do the same task without a computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so it seems you want to mask your input with an alternation/checkerboard pattern:

```
import numpy as np

def checkerboard(shape):
    "A hacky way to generate a checkerboard"
    return np.sum(np.indices(shape), axis=0) % 2 == 0

data = np.ones((10, 10), dtype=np.bool)

# equivalent ways of applying the mask to your array
result = data & checkerboard(data.shape)

# or 
result = np.logical_and(data, checkerboard(data.shape))
```

i.e. `checkerboard((5, 5))` returns

```
array([[ True, False,  True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: What do you mean by that? What if you change `== 0` to `== 1`?

Comment: I was thinking of using some inbuilt functions in numpy/skimage...Is not it really?