# Extract indices of a 2D binary array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, scikit-image

I have a numpy array (data) consisting of 0 and 1.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                 [1, 1, **1**, 1, 1, 0],
                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

I want to extract the indices where '1' is surrounded by neighboring 5*5 elements consisting of 1s.

The expected index is shown by asterisks, i.e, (3,3).
An answer in the form of a boolean array is also okay.

```
[[False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False]
 [False False **True** False False False]
 [False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False]]
```

I tried as

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_erosion


kernel = np.ones((5,5))

result = binary_erosion(data, kernel)
print result

[[False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False]
 [False False  True False False False]
 [False False  True False False False]
 [False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False]]
```

It produced two 'True' positions but I want only one at (3,3).

How to do it?

**EDIT: The solution shown in the linked question too gives the unexpected answer.**

Comment: The second element marked as `True` is also surrounded by a 5x5 box of `1`s... why don't you like it?

Comment: @6502 It is because counting the 1s from  the locations already taken by the first True. I want to avoid repeating such..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract Indices of a NumPy Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512485/extract-indices-of-a-numpy-array)

Comment: @Divakar nope, I saw that question before asking, but the solution shown in that question too gives the unexpected answer as I maintained in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively to `binary_erosion`, you could use the `scipy.ndimage.generic_filter` to achieve this,

```
from scipy.ndimage import generic_filter
generic_filter(data, np.all, size=(5,5), mode='constant', cval=0).astype(np.bool)
```

However you would obtain the same results as above,

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])  # using 1, 0 instead of True, False for readability
```

because it is the correct answer to your question. The 6 rows in your example matrix are symmetric, and with the given kernel, there would be 2 symmetric `True` element in the result.

If you want to avoid this, you could use a non symmetric-kernel size: `size=(6,5)`, although this produces one true element in row 3 not row 2. This could be fixed, manually padding the `kernel` array with zeros when using `binary_erosion`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer with explainations. Is not it possible to read the data from top-left position for only 5 columns and 5 rows; then if all elements are 1, extract mid index of it and so on..?

Comment: Well, `scipy.ndimage` works with pixel, and it simply does not have the concept of "mid-pixel or mid-index". Of course it is possible to do it, for instance increasing the resolution by with `ndimage.zoom` doing the `binary_erosion`, and going back to the initial resolutions. Still because, your original array is up-down symmetric, you would have to somehow break this symmetry to get only 1 pixel.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach similar to the one of @rth

As your data is made of `1` and `0`, you can put it in an `int` array and use a [`uniform_filter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.uniform_filter.html) to achieve the same:

```
>>> mask = uniform_filter(data, 5, mode='constant')
>>> mask
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

The mean of ones that are not surrounded by ones is less than `1` and is rounded to `0` as it is an integer array.

To get the first index you could do something like:

```
>>> y, x = np.where(mask)
>>> y[0], x[0]
(2, 2)
```